# Не получается убрать скролл

Tags: wpf

Не получается убрать скролл, и сделать при клике на лист меню,  чтобы он поднялся вверх.
Можете помочь, сделать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
   <Grid>
            <Border CornerRadius="5" Background="#FF303030" Margin="75,308,43,33">
                <ListBox Name="Losters"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding ServersData}"
                 Background="Transparent"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedServer}" 
                 BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
                 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local1:ServerData}">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Ellipse Height="14" Width="14" Margin="8"
                                 Fill="{Binding NameColor}" />
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Foreground="White"
                                       FontWeight="Bold"
                                       FontSize="18">
                                  <Run Text="{Binding NameColor}"/>
                                  <Run Text="сервер"/>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock Foreground="LightSlateGray">
                                  <Run Text="Онлайн:"/>
                                  <Run Text="{Binding Count}" Foreground="White"/>
                                  <Run Text="из"/>
                                  <Run Text="{Binding TotalCount, Source={StaticResource ServersVM}}"/>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
```

Comment: А как вы его отключаете? То, что у вас на картинке — это вертикальный скролл

Comment: @АндрейNOP Невнимательность, а со втором поможете? Чтобы нажать на него, и список поднялся вверх

Comment: Мне непонятно что вы имеете ввиду, опишите подробнее, можно с эскизом того что хотите получить